# Почему в Math.random() не выпадает ноль?

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

По любой ссылке в поиске, мне выдается, что `Math.random()` должен вывести число между 0 (**включительно**) и 1 (невключительно).

Но, данный метод возвращает все что угодно, но не ровный ноль, а например `6.674303110187907e-9`, либо `9.311085236163308e-11`, даже если передаю аргумент `< 0.000000001`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115117/discussion-on-question-by-vadim---math-random---).

Comment: Там 17 знаков-то после запятой) Возможных комбинаций 10^17. Если допустить, что в секунду происходит миллион операций, `10**17/1000000/3600/24/365` нуля будете ждать в среднем 3170 лет ))

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME разве не 16?

Comment: @Vadim, не нужно вандализировать собственные сообщения после исправления ошибок.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ради интереса решил заглянуть в [исходники V8](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/refs/heads/master/src/base/utils/random-number-generator.h). Код генерации случайного числа с плавающей точкой из полуинтервала `[0.0, 1.0)` выглядит так (упрощённо):

```
double NextDouble()
{
    uint64_t random_value = get_uint64_random_value_by_XorShift128();
    
    uint64_t exponent = 0x3FF0000000000000;
    uint64_t random   = (random_value >> 12) | exponent;
    
    double result = bit_cast<double>(random) - 1.0; //скопировали побайтово.
    return result;
}
```

Сперва генерируется 64-битное беззнаковое равномерно распределённое псевдослучайное число `random_value`.

Затем это число с помощью битовых операций приводится к следующему виду (в двоичном представлении):

```
0 | 011 1111 1111 | xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

Символами `x` здесь обозначены биты полученные из переменной `random_value`. Всего **52 бита**.

Данная последовательность бит однозначно задаёт некоторое число с плавающей точкой из полуинтервала `[1.0, 2.0)`. Вот некоторые конкретные значения:

```
0 | 011 1111 1111 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 == 1.0
0 | 011 1111 1111 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 ≈ 1.0000000000000002
...
0 | 011 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 ≈ 1.9999999999999996
0 | 011 1111 1111 | 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 ≈ 1.9999999999999998
```

Затем целое беззнаковое 64-битное число с помощью `bit_cast` преобразуется в соответствующее число с плавающей точкой. (`bit_cast` — это функция, которая просто копирует байты, составляющие переменную `random` типа `uint64_t` в переменную типа `double`.)

И наконец, из числа с плавающей точкой из полуинтервала `[1.0, 2.0)` вычитается единица, чтобы получить значение в полуинтервале `[0.0, 1.0)`.

Чтобы функция `NextDouble` вернула ноль, необходимо, чтобы все биты, обозначаемые символом `x`, были равны нулю. В предположении, что любая комбинация битов `x` равновероятна, получаем вероятность наступления такого события, равную `1 / 2**52 = 1 / 4 503 599 627 370 496 ≈ 2,22044604925031308e-16`

Также заметим, что минимальное число с плавающей точкой среди всех чисел с плавающей точкой, которые больше нуля, и которое может вернуть функция `NextDouble` равно `1.0000000000000002 - 1.0 ≈ 2.2204460492503131e-16`. То есть функция `NextDouble` никода не вернёт число из интервала `(0.0, 2.2204460492503131e-16)`.

---

Число `1 / 2**52` куда меньше, чем может показаться на первый взгляд. Шанс того, что мы не получим ни одного нулевого значения, вызывая функцию `NextDouble` каждую секунду по 10 000 000 раз на протяжении года равен ([WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28+%28+2%5E52+-+1%29+%2F+2%5E52+%29%5E%28+10000000+*+60+*+60+*+24+*+365+%29)):

```
( ( 2^52 - 1) / 2^52 )^( 10 000 000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 ) ≈ 0.932
```

Answer (score 7):

Потому что вероятность выпадения ровно 0 точно такая же маленькая, как выпадение любого конкретного числа между 0 и верхней границей, т.е. это тоже самое, что вы бы спрашивали, почему не выпадает число 1.2345678910e-11, например, или любое другое. Обычная теория вероятности, ничего необычного.

Comment: Это в идеале, конечно же. На практике ещё влияет представление и точность чисел в памяти.

Comment: @Kromster Конечно. Конкретное число может и вообще не выпасть никогда просто из-за того, что этот тип данных не умеет это число в точности представлять.